# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json eats node

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

ConvertFrom-Json is failing to successfully parse my Json into object, despite my object being legal Json.

I'm using the latest version of Powershell.

When I try parsing a google request JSON body like this:

```
{
    "reportScope":  {
                        "agencyId":  "11111111111111111",
                        "advertiserId":  "22222222222222222"
                    },
    "reportType":  "adGroup",
    "columns":  [
                    {
                        "columnName":  "status"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "date"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "account"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "accountType"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "campaign"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "adGroup"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "deviceSegment"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "impr"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "clicks"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "dfaRevenue"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "cost"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "avgPos"
                    }
                ],
    "timeRange":  {
                      "startDate":  "2017-09-13",
                      "endDate":  "2017-08-14"
                  },
    "filters":  [
                    {
                        "column":  {"columnName":  "impr"},
                        "operator":  "greaterThan",
                        "values":  "0"
                    }
                ],
    "downloadFormat":  "csv",
    "maxRowsPerFile":  6000000,
    "statisticsCurrency":  "agency",
    "verifySingleTimeZone":  "false",
    "includeRemovedEntities":  "false"
}
```

I get an object like this:

```
[DBG]: PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\psDashboard>> $objJson


reportScope            : @{agencyId=11111111111111111; advertiserId=22222222222222222}
reportType             : adGroup
columns                : {@{columnName=status}, @{columnName=date}, @{columnName=account}, @{columnName=accountType}...}
timeRange              : @{startDate=2017-09-13; endDate=2017-08-14}
filters                : {@{column=; operator=greaterThan; values=0}}
downloadFormat         : csv
maxRowsPerFile         : 6000000
statisticsCurrency     : agency
verifySingleTimeZone   : false
includeRemovedEntities : false




[DBG]: PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\psDashboard>> $objJson.filters

column operator    values
------ --------    ------
       greaterThan 0
```

Notice `column` should contain `@{columnNane=imgr}` but it instead contains nothing.

Code used for parsing:

```
$objJson = Get-Content -Path $FileName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No problems on my end (Powershell 5 on Windows 10). I do get the @{columnName=impr} ... I did put your requesti n a file and imported it using your parsing line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i took your code and was able to get to the object you are looking for I first put it in a Here string @""@ and was able to get to it.. then like you I put it in a variable and piped to convertfrom-json and got the ame results.

```
$test = @"
{
    "reportScope":  {
                        "agencyId":  "11111111111111111",
                        "advertiserId":  "22222222222222222"
                    },
    "reportType":  "adGroup",
    "columns":  [
                    {
                        "columnName":  "status"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "date"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "account"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "accountType"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "campaign"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "adGroup"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "deviceSegment"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "impr"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "clicks"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "dfaRevenue"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "cost"
                    },
                    {
                        "columnName":  "avgPos"
                    }
                ],
    "timeRange":  {
                      "startDate":  "2017-09-13",
                      "endDate":  "2017-08-14"
                  },
    "filters":  [
                    {
                        "column":  {"columnName":  "impr"},
                        "operator":  "greaterThan",
                        "values":  "0"
                    }
                ],
    "downloadFormat":  "csv",
    "maxRowsPerFile":  6000000,
    "statisticsCurrency":  "agency",
    "verifySingleTimeZone":  "false",
    "includeRemovedEntities":  "false"
}
"@
$t = $test | ConvertFrom-Json

$t.filters.column

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $t.filters

column             operator    values
------             --------    ------
@{columnName=impr} greaterThan 0     



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $t.filters.column

columnName
----------
impr
```

Using get content and using convertfrom-json.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>     $test.filters

column             operator    values
------             --------    ------
@{columnName=impr} greaterThan 0     



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>     $test.filters.column

columnName
----------
impr
```

could it be your version of convertFrom-json my module version is:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> gcm convertfrom-json

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-Json                                   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility

Comment: Hi thom, I actually found an answer in the Python bug thread. It turns out that like other objects when a string is piped into ConvertFrom-JSON it drops any single item arrays - strange, but they guys over at the Python bug logging say it is buy design.  After I put my Get-Contents in one variable and then put that Variable in ConvertFrom-Json (ie no pipe) it worked.  I'd rather not answer my own question and since you're already on the right track would you mind typing it up?  If you do i'll mark it right.